# Unable to fetch Bitmap while decryption of an Image in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, bitmap

In my application I want to encrypt/decrypt all the images for offline mode. But while decryption I don't want to write the same decrypted image and I need to fetch Bitmap from byte[]. The conversion of byte[] to Bitmap always returns null and at the same time I was able to write the image using same byte[].

```
/**
 * 
 * @param srcPath
 * @param destPath
 * 
 *            Encrypts the file in srcPath and creates a file in destPath
 */
public void encrypt(String srcPath, String destPath) {
    File rawFile = new File(srcPath);
    File encryptedFile = new File(destPath);
    InputStream inStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        /**
         * Initialize the cipher for encryption
         */
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        /**
         * Initialize input and output streams
         */
        inStream = new FileInputStream(rawFile);
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));
            outStream.flush();
        }
        outStream.write(cipher.doFinal());
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param srcPath
 * @param destPath
 * 
 *            Decrypts the file in srcPath and creates a file in destPath
 */
public Bitmap decrypt(String srcPath, String decPath) {
    File encryptedFile = new File(srcPath);
    File deFile = new File(decPath);

    InputStream inStream = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStream outStreamm=null;
    byte[] buffer1 = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        /**
         * Initialize the cipher for decryption
         */
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        /**
         * Initialize input and output streams
         */
        inStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
        outStreamm = new FileOutputStream(deFile);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));
        }
        buffer1 = (outStream.toByteArray());
        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer1, 0, buffer1.length);
        outStreamm.write(buffer1);
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
        outStreamm.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

What should be the conditions for the byte[] cannot be converted to bitmap?

Comment: `But while decryption I don't want to write the same decrypted image` .. Sorry. Dont understand a word of that. `and I need to fetch Bitmap from byte[].`. Sorry this goes to quick. Cannot follow you.

Comment: I don't want to create a decrypted copy of the file but at the same time I need bitmap of decrypted one before writing so that I can display in my application. Now I think this comment will make things clear.

Comment: No. Because why you would declare your function like `Bitmap decrypt(String srcPath, String decPath)` then? Declare it like `Bitmap decrypt(String srcPath)` and everybody would understand.

Comment: Yeah its right. I was just testing that weather the byte[] is corrupted or not. After I find this working i will change it that Bitmap decrypt(String srcPath).

Comment: But i find your approach not ok. You encrypt a file. Its probably an image file. You encrypt it to another file. A decrypt function would do the reverse only. But your decrypt function will make a Bitmap out of it. That has little to do with decryption.

Comment: But are you able to decrypt it to a file? And is the resulting file byte by byte equal to the original? You should be able to do that first.

Comment: Actually I am showing only a demo of the original version. I have to download the image from the server and need to encrypt the image in between or I shall delete the original version of it programmatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77684/discussion-between-akhilesh-sk-and-greenapps).

Comment: Instead of a `FileOutputStream` declare -well you did that already- a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and use it.